# Adding a form for filtering results while sticking to Zend URL structure without query strings

Tags: zend-framework

Assume a routing/URL structure like

```
http://www.example.com/vehicles/manage
```

Where this page lists vehicles from the database. If I want to add a form for filtering the result by, for example colour, I will end up with a URL to which the filtration forms GET action adds the query string e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/vehicles/manage?colour=blue
```

When I really want to stick to the URL structure

```
http://www.example.com/vehicles/manage/colour/blue
```

I would prefer not to have query strings anywhere in my application, but there are countless examples in the adminitrative interface where tabulated results will have to be filtered to make them manageable. Any alternative solutions are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What is the code that builds your URL? Do you use the url view helper ?

Comment: @joellord, yes I use the url view helper and gotoRoute in the controller. However, if I have "filter forms" which postback to the calling page, the GET action triggers the URL to be assembled with a query string appended (not sure exactly when/where that occurs).

Comment: if you are using forms for this, use POST, no query string.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but I was hoping to keep the filter parameters in the URL for the normal reasons, so the URL is descriptive, and so that it can be bookmarked/linked to etc. Basically, I've come to the conclusion that this is not possible without some nasty redirecting in the controller. I thought maybe I was just missing something. I've done a quick survey of active zend apps (e.g. magento), and for form driven results filters, you always end up with query strings. So be it. Thanks for your suggstions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Redirector action helper to achieve this.

Instantiate it with this:

> $redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();

Then just pass your module / controller / action / params to it like so:

> return $redirector->direct('manage', 'vehicles', 'default', $params));

Where `$params` would contain your filters, something like:

> array('colour' => 'blue', 'wheel_trims' => 'alloy');

Hope that helps :>

Edit: Oh, and to get your values in manageAction() just do:

> $request = $this->getRequest();
>   $params = $request->getParams();